# Update list item with itemadded event receivers sp2013

Tags: event-receivers

I have an itemadded event receivers for a List, my ItemAdded function here:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
            string a= item["a"].ToString();
            string b= item["b"].ToString().Trim();
// Sure that 'b' is not empty
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(b))
            {
                item["b"] = a;
                item.Update();
            }

        }
```

But nothing happen after I added the item???
I'm a new in Event Receiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment the line  `base.ItemAdded(properties);` and try it will update the item and instead of `.toString()` use `Convert.toString(object);`. Even null value would be handled.

Comment: Can you explain why removing base.ItemAdded(properties); resolves this issue?

Comment: base.ItemAdded(properties);  is to override the base class  SPItemEventReceiver    method so you are passing the current property to that method after that you  are trying to modify the item so the property remained same